# jquery - move table rows, assign order values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work out how to move rows and set an ordering value against them.

I've got quite a simple table layout. The data is being passed from a backend management system which I have no control over.

My table ends up looking like this:

```
<table id='sites'>
<tr id="0" data-site="SITE:1" data-order="1" data-siteid="12456232" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE1
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>


<tr id="5" data-site="SITE:3" data-order="3" data-siteid="78565213" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE3
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>


<tr id="8" data-site="SITE:4" data-order="4" data-siteid="36587492" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE4
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

<tr id="6" data-site="SITE:2" data-order="2" data-siteid="02365874" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE2
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

</table>
```

The rows I'm showing are section rows, there may be other rows in the table but these are the only ones I'm currently interested in .

Each row has a unique `ID`, a `data-site` and a `data-order`. As the information can be passed to the script in any order, I'm using the following to sort the rows using the `data-order` attribute :

```
var $table=$('#sites');
var rows = $table.find('tr.site_heading').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('data-order');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('data-order');
    if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

This can be seen working [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/v16ruh96/)

Each row needs to be able to move up order down the table and then have it's `data-order` updated. This is quite simple as I'm only moving one row at a time  effectivity swapping two rows positions.

If I move a row up I swap the `data-order` value with the row it's moved above and if I move a row down I swap it's `data-order` with the row it's moved below.

All this works great... Until I get rows with NO `data-order` value.
These rows don't get ordered onload as there is no attribute to compare against.  I need the ability to be able to move a row up or down and have it assigned the next order value.

I've created a new [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/v16ruh96/2/) which shows the same table but with 3 new rows that have no data-order value assigned.

If I move any of the sites with no data-order value assigned UP they should get  the next data-order value (5) unless they are swapping positions with a row that has a data-order value assigned and then they should get that value and the row they swapped with gets the next value (5).

And the reverse if moving down..

Has anyone got any ideas how I can do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be "to force" a `data-order` on `sort`...
**Here is how I reworked your code:**
*(starting with the fiddle containing the 3 rows with empty `data-order`)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $('#sites');
  var rows = $table.find('tr.site_heading').get();

  function RowOrder() {
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      var keyA = $(a).attr('data-order');
      var keyB = $(b).attr('data-order');
      if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;
      if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
      if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
      return 0;
    });

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
      $table.children('tbody').append(row);//.attr("data-order", index+1);
    });

    // Set data-order
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
      $(this).attr("data-order", index+1);
    });
  }
  RowOrder();

  $('.up').on('click', function() {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var prevRow = $(this).closest("tr").prev(".site_heading");

    newOrder = prevRow.attr("data-order");
    oldOrder = thisRow.attr("data-order");

    thisRow.attr("data-order", newOrder);
    prevRow.attr("data-order", oldOrder);
    RowOrder();
  });

  $('.down').on('click', function() {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var nextRow = $(this).closest("tr").next(".site_heading");

    oldOrder = thisRow.attr("data-order");
    newOrder = nextRow.attr("data-order");

    thisRow.attr("data-order", newOrder);
    nextRow.attr("data-order", oldOrder);
    RowOrder();
  });
});
```

As you can see... There are many small changes.
I made a function out of your "sort part" of your script, so we can call it on a `.up` and `.down` click.

An `id` must be unique... That's why these up/down links are now classes.

You can see it in action on [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/gnjnejyh/).
Hit F12 and select a row to see the `data-order` attribute changes.